# Can I log a custom event to Firebase Analytics from a Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have a Google Assistant action with Firebase fulfilment via Cloud Function. I would like to also log custom events to the projects Analytics instance. Is it possible to do this? Do I need to use the Firebase Admin framework so it has automatic access to the Analytics instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to log analytics events from backend code.  They can only be logged directly from the web or mobile app itself using the provided client SDK.

Comment: That's a bummer. I could write some event data to the Firestore I guess?